# Insertion sort explanation

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am trying to understand the code of insertion sort, but i am really confused and i don't understand what i,j,index are doing in the code.. Can someone please help me understand more

```
Procedure InsertionSort(numbers : Array of Integer; size : Integer);
Var i, j, index : Integer


    Begin
     For i := 2 to size-1 do
      Begin
       index := numbers[i];
       j := i;
       While ((j > 1) AND (numbers[j-1] > index)) do
        Begin
         numbers[j] := numbers[j-1];
         j := j - 1;
        End;
       numbers[j] := index;
      End;

    End.
```

Comment: Here i is the number of passes and numbers[j] points at the current integer that is being sorted.

Comment: @ParagKadam but i'm still confused, what does this code do? 
"For i := 2 to size-1 do"

Comment: I am a java developer but from this code it looks like it is trying to sort the array from 2nd index postion(i.e from the 3rd number in the array) onwards upto the entire array(size - 1).

Comment: @ParagKadam so that's a correct way to use the insertion sort? or is this bubble sort?

Comment: Bubble sort only ever switches neighboring elements while insertion sort picks up an element, searches a 'better' place for it and inserts it at this place moving all following elements on place further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo, the name `index` may be somewhat misleading. In this context I would have called it `currentValue` or something like that. That said:

Imagine an *numbers -> [5, 3, 7, 2, 9, 1, 8, 4]*

The algorithm start at 2 so:

```
i == 2; currentValue := numbers[i] (== 7)
```

Now the algorithm move all values located in indices (j) `< i` as long as `j > 1` with a value `< 7` one place up:

```
numbers[1] == 3 < 7 -> numbers[2] = 3
numbers[0] == 5 < 7 -> numbers[1] = 5
```

and finally write `currentValue` into `numbers[0]`. So the result after first pass would be

```
[7, 5, 3, 2, 9, 1, 8, 4]
```

Second pass (2 is smaller than any thing in the places before, so nothing happens):

```
[7, 5, 3, 2, 9, 1, 8, 4]
```

Third pass (9 is largest element in `numbers[0]` to `numbers[4]`):

```
[9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 8, 4]
```

and so on ...